# Scala string splitting in decending amounts of char

Tags: string, scala, scala-collections

Given a string such as

```
val s = (0 to 9).mkString
s: String = 0123456789
```

striving to find a functional (neat) approach to get an `Array[String]` like this

```
Array("0123", "456", "78", "9")
```

Using `substring` on pre-calculated indexes proves quite messy.

**Update** The array size `n` and the string length `l` are related, always, by

```
val l = n*(n+1)/2
```

Put another way, input strings for n = 1,2,... have length 1,3,6,10,15,... Thus as noted by @m-z a string like `0123456789a` has no solution.

Comment: What happens when it can't be split like that? `"0123456789a"`

Comment: @m-z thanks, excellent observation, note update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator.from(0).map { i => 
    s.dropRight(i*(i+1)/2).takeRight(i+1)
}.takeWhile(!_.isEmpty).toList.reverse
```

Or recursion:

```
def incSplit(s: String, iter: Int = 1): List[String] = s match {
    case "" => Nil
    case s => incSplit(s.dropRight(iter), iter + 1) :+ s.takeRight(iter)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution

```
  val s = "0123456789" 
  (4 to 1 by -1).foldLeft((s,List[String]()))
                         {case ((t, res), n) => 
                            (t.drop(n), t.take(n)::res)}
                ._2
                .reverse
```

Each time we take off the first n characters from our string, add that to the result and pass the string (minus the first n characters) to the next iteration

EDIT: All of the answers so far are ugly. So here's one that is more elegant (IMO)

```
val s = "0123456789"
    //> s  : String = 0123456789
val indicies = (4 to 1 by -1).scanLeft(0) {_ + _}
    //> indicies  : List[Int] = List(0, 4, 7, 9, 10)
val slices = indicies zip indicies.tail   
    //> slices  : List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,4), (4,7), (7,9), (9,10))
for ((start,end) <- slices) yield s.slice(start, end)
    //> res1: List[String] = List(0123, 456, 78, 9)
```